# Socket communication between desktop application and server

Tags: java, .net, spring, sockets, websocket

I need to be able to synchronize PC desktop application (.NET) with my server (Java), instead the PC will always ask the server if there is something new (polling) I thought about open socket protocol between the two which means if there is something new the server will notify the PC directly.

The first thing I saw is web socket protocol which is nicely supported in Spring 4 framework (good for my server), the thing is that the protocol isn't supported in the .NET framework running in my PC app.

Is it possible to use the open socket protocol in my server side but the PC app will communicate with lower level protocol?

I never implemented that kind of communication before I usually stick to REST protocol can some shed some light on the subject?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In case web socket is not an option on the .NET side, adding long polling to the server side might be a step in the right direction.

[Long polling in spring using DeferredResult](http://java.dzone.com/articles/long-polling-spring-32s)